# Remove header in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm writing my PhD thesis in overleaf.

I have included a "List of Figures" chapter in the preface. Preface has roman page letters, chapters start on odd page number, and chapters are included it in TOC.

However, in the \listoffigures there is also a header.
How can I remove this extra header, without interrupting with the preface style I wan?

`[heading=none]` does the work in my Bibliography chapter, but doesn't seem to work on `\listoffigures`

My List of Figures chapter looks like this:

```
\pdfbookmark[0]{List of Figures}{List of Figures}
\chapter*{List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\label{chap:list_figures}

\listoffigures
```

And it's a separate tex file called with

```
\input{frontbackmatter/list_figures.tex}   % INCLUDE List of figures
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t remove that, but you can remove the one that you add yourself. You have given way to little information to give a definite answer but try to replace

`\chapter*{List of Figures}`

with

`\newpage`

Comment: Thx it solved my problem. Replaced ```\newpage``` with ```\cleardoublepage``` when needed to ensure new chapters only starts on odd pages